# How to supply header when mocking fetch?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock the `fetch` call in my create-react app but the test fails since it doesn't match the required headers.

Here is my code under test:

```
 const serviceHeaders = {
    headers: {
      'CONSUMER.ID': process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_CONSUMER_ID,
      'SERVICE.NAME': process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_NAME,
      'SERVICE.ENV': "dev"
    }
  };

  const localhostURL = "http://localhost:8080";
 useEffect(() => {
    let itemURL = localhostURL + '/items/';
    fetch(itemURL, serviceHeaders).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then(data => {
                setItems(data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Successful request to retrieve items but could not parse body as json", error);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

and the test:

```
const fetchMock = jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => 
  Promise.resolve({ ok: true, json: () => Promise.resolve([{itemName: 'Color', itemId: 23},
  {itemName: 'Car', itemId: 34}])}));

const localhostURL = "http://localhost:8080";
act(() => { render(<ItemSelection/>) });

expect(fetchMock).toBeCalledWith(localhostURL + '/items/');
```

Is there a way to supply headers to `spyOn()` or is there another way to achieve it? I'm using jest and react-testing library.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mock fetch, I would use an HTTP interceptor like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock). That way you can test behavior vs testing implementation details. With an HTTP interceptor, you can reply based on specific headers too.

```
it('gives users options to choose from', async () => { // <-- notice async for server to respond
  const mockData = [
    {itemName: 'Color', itemId: 23},
    {itemName: 'Car', itemId: 34}
  ];
  nock(`${yoursite}`, {
      reqheaders: {
        'CONSUMER.ID': process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_CONSUMER_ID,
        'SERVICE.NAME': process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_NAME,
        'SERVICE.ENV': "dev"
      },
    })
    .get('/items')
    .reply(200, {data: mockData});
  
  const {queryAllByTestId} = render(<ItemSelection/>);
  await waitFor(() => expect(queryAllByTestId('item-option').length > 0).toBe(true)); // <-- Waiting for server to kick over
});
```

Comment: In your example is `nock` the interceptor?